# Node-Cron keeping NodeJS Server busy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron, cron-task

**Working of Cron**

In my mongoDB Collection Each document is associated with a date,
I'm checking if that date is passed and status of that object is Active then Send Notification

**Like this**

```
cron.schedule('* * * * * *', () => {
    collection.find()
    .then((docs) => {
      docs.forEach(async (doc) => {
        // Check if date passed
        let passed = checkIfToday(doc.date)
        
        if(doc.status === "Active" && passed === true) {
          // send Notification
          activity(doc._id, "Reminder For status", "doc", [], doc._id, null, null, null)
        }
      });
    })
  });
```

**But This Cron Job keeping my server busy**

Cron is executing perfectly but,
if I make any request to server its not responding

**what is the best way to do it ?**

Comment: One crons job shouldn't be any problem what server are you using?
1. Usuallly if you are on microservices architecture you can set up queues in separate microservice. 2. You can deploy them on separate server separate from your main server.
3. Or you can convert your function into API and there are some websites which can call the api every second.

Comment: for now, I'm testing on local machine, is there a way I can put it on main NodeJS backend?

Comment: 1. Convert your cron job function into a simple API.
2. Create a separate Node js server.
3. Run cron job on that server.
4, Call the API which you just created in the main app from the new server.